# Portioning data with a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I am trying to create to partition two data sets conditional on the value in a column.

```
    #initialize empty data frames
    test =data.frame(D=factor(),
                B=factor(), 
                 P=factor(), 
                 u=double(),
                 t=character(),stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 

    train =data.frame(D=factor(),
             B=factor(), 
             P=factor(), 
             u=double(),
             t=character(),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)    
#loop over  each row          
for(i in nrow(knime.in))
{
    if(knime.in[i,5]=="train")
        {
            train=rbind(knime.in[i,])
        }
    else
        {
            test=rbind(knime.in[i,])
        }

}
```

When I do this I find everything in the test frame, even though I can see the first half or so values have a train value in column 5.

Comment: You've written your if block sloppily. `} else {` instead of having them on 3 different lines.

Comment: I fixed that, although that didn't actually resolve the error.

Comment: Why not `train = knime.in[knime.in$t == 'train', ]` and similarly for `test` vectorized?

Comment: So, you want to separate your data based on the value in column 5, if it is equal to "train"?

Comment: Yes, if the string in column 5 is "train" the row is bound to the train dataframe. I did just realize syntax is train=rbind(train, knime.in[i,]), but this still did not resolve my error. It looks to be something with the conditional.

Comment: there are other alternatives like split or filter (package dplyr).

Answer (score 0):

Just index.

```
train <- knime.in[knime.in[,5]=="train",]
test <- knime.in[knime.in[,5]!="train",]
```